# I want to parse JSON data and display it on the website but error is Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, mern

This is what the output looks like.

```
{
  dataset: {
    id: 9775687,
    dataset_code: 'FB',
    database_code: 'WIKI',
    name: 'Facebook Inc. (FB) Prices, Dividends, Splits and Trading Volume',
    description: 'End of day open, high, low, close and volume, dividends and splits, and split/dividend adjusted open, high, low close and volume for Facebook, Inc. (FB). Ex-Dividend is non-zero on ex-dividend dates. Split Ratio is 1 on non-split dates. Adjusted prices are calculated per CRSP (www.crsp.com/products/documentation/crsp-calculations)\n' +
      '\n' +
          'This data is in the public domain. You may copy, distribute, disseminate or include the data in other products for commercial and/or noncommercial purposes.\n' +
          '\n' +
          "This data is part of Quandl's Wiki initiative to get financial data permanently into the public domain. Quandl relies on users like you to flag errors and provide data where data is wrong or missing. Get involved: connect@quandl.com\n",
        refreshed_at: '2018-03-27T21:46:11.036Z',
        newest_available_date: '2018-03-27',
        oldest_available_date: '2012-05-18',
        column_names: [ 'Date', 'Close' ],
        frequency: 'daily',
        type: 'Time Series',
        premium: false,
        transform: 'rdiff',
        column_index: 4,
        start_date: '2014-01-01',
        end_date: '2014-12-31',
        data: [
          [Array], [Array],
          [Array], [Array],
          [Array], [Array],
          [Array]
        ],
        collapse: 'monthly',
        order: 'desc',
        database_id: 4922
    }
}
```

**I want to use this data and display it on my website.**

**The code I am using is as follows:**

```
var unirest = require("unirest");

var req = unirest("GET", "https://quandl1.p.rapidapi.com/datasets/WIKI/FB.json");

req.query({
    "start_date": "2014-01-01",
    "transform": "rdiff",
    "column_index": "4",
    "collapse": "monthly",
    "end_date": "2014-12-31",
    "order": "desc"
});

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "quandl1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "e9255b460cmsh863ffa7bd83b3bep19d626jsne90553c61953"
});

var data;

req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
    data = res.body;
});

var output = data.dataset.dataset_code;

var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'))

app.get('/apidata', function(req, res){
    res.send(output);
}) 

app.listen(3000);
```

The output is not showing the data and showing Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

How can I extract the data to a new variable and show it in HTML using hbs?

Comment: What is the expected format the code is suppose to come back as? Have you tried res.json() or res.text() to see what you are getting back?

Comment: How Do I display this data in my website?

Comment: I am getting the data in a proper format but I cannot use it to display in my website.